# No rule to make target in GCC Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

This is the following Makefile at issue:

```
#
# Compiler flags
#
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra 

#
# Project files
# example - 
# SRCS = hash_table.c linked_list.c utils.c common.c business_logic.c user_interface.c
# SRCS = test/gc_test.c src/gc.c
SRCS := $(shell find . -name "*")
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXE  = output.out

FILENAMES := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c" -printf "%f\n")
FILENAMES_OUT = $(FILENAMES:.c=.o)
#
# Default build settings
#
BUILDDIR = build
BUILDCFLAGS = -g -O0
BUILDEXE = $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXE)
BUILDOBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(FILENAMES_OUT))


# Rules for default build
all: clean build

build: $(BUILDEXE)

$(BUILDEXE): $(BUILDOBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BUILDCFLAGS) -o $(BUILDEXE) $^ -lcunit

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BUILDCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


memtest: $(BUILDEXE) 
    valgrind --leak-check=full ./$<


#
# Other rules
#
clean:
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
```

**PROBLEM** -> `` make: *** No rule to make target `build/gc_test.o', needed by `build/output.out'.  Stop. ``

**PROJECT TREE**

```
.
├── build
├── doc
│   └── design.md
├── Makefile
├── proj
│   ├── code_quality_report.md
│   ├── deviations.md
│   ├── individual_reflection.md
│   ├── team_reflection.md
│   └── test_report.md
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── gc.c
│   └── headers
│       └── gc.h
└── tests
    └── gc_test.c
```

The issue itself happens in `$(BUILDEXE): $(BUILDOBJS)` where the dependencies are `gc_test.c gc.c`. Those dependencies SHOULD get caught in the function below it, because it's input is all the .c files in the `build` directory. Those files SHOULD get properly matched and then compiled to .o files which then should climb up the tree and produce an executable. I'm confused because `$(BUILDOBJS)` should be the same as `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o`.

I'm new to making Makefiles, but I want to get better at it. Please point out better naming conventions or terminology that could have been used better for this post. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you do this line explicitly (i.e. with manually hardcoded file names) instead of trying to magically find all .c files? `FILENAMES := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c" -printf "%f\n")`. Globbing like that is often a problem for make setups as far as I know.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Shows the same error. It's very strange.

Comment: You state `"...because it's input is all the .c files in the build directory"` regarding the rule `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c` .  That's incorrect.  The dependency (`gc_test.c` in this case) will be searched for in the current directory (or under any relevant `vpath` locations) since `%.c` expands to `gc_test.c`.

Comment: ... and `gc_test.c` is not present in the current directory.  If you want to continue with building objects into a special, separate directory instead of into the same directory as their sources or a parallel build tree then you will need a separate rule for each folder that contains sources you want to compile.  Honestly, though, I never have figured out why so many people insist on doing that.  It is more brittle and takes more work to maintain, and I don't see what it achieves that cannot be achieved instead by a VPATH build or even a good "clean" rule.

Comment: `vpath` is a good solution to this problem. (I'd Answer, but @G.M. mentioned it 40 minutes before I got here.)

Comment: It's not building objects in a different directory that's the problem.  that's easy to support and is super-handy for many reasons: for example you can have different object directories for code built with different flags (debug, optimized, SAN, etc.) and also it makes cleanup of objects a breeze.  The problem is trying to use a different directory structure for objects than is used for sources; often people try to put all object files into a single directory even though sources live in multiple directories.  **THAT** is annoying and complex to support.

Comment: If you make the object directory structure identical to the source directory structure, with just a `OBJDIR` prefix on it or similar, then it's bog-simple to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
FILENAMES := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c" -printf "%f\n")
```

This is wrong because `-printf "%f\n"` prints *only* the filenames, without any path.  You're losing all information about the path where files are found, so how can make find them?

You should change this to simply `-print` then it will work.